# Standard model of  ZFC

Tags: set-theory

Is  ZFC+Con(ZFC)  powerful enough to show there isn't  any standard model of  ZFC? What you think about it?

Comment: Are you sure that the question you stated is the one you really wanted to ask?  What you're asking is, as long as there exists _some_ model of ZFC, does it follow that _no_ models are standard?  Maybe you meant to ask, as long as there exists _some_ model of ZFC, does it follow that _some_ model is standard?

Comment: A clarification: I believe Jaykov is referring to the content of a posting he made to the Foundations of Mathematics email list, about a purported proof that ZFC has no well-founded models, which led to a discussion about models of ZFC. With Jaykov's permission, I can post a link to the original email (the FOM archives are public and searchable, so in principle anyone can find it, but I would rather not link it without permission), which contains a link to the purported proof. If this is correct, I would like to point out that MO is not for testing conjectures or checking original work.

Comment: Timothy Chow >What you're asking is, as long as there exists some model of ZFC, does it follow that no models are standard?
Yes of course.

Comment: I'm asking does it follow from ZFC+ there exists some model of ZFC 

Comment: Jaykov, as I explain in my answer, if this were true, it would refute all large cardinal axioms. Are you claiming to have such a proof? 
 


Comment: No, because the axioms of ZFC + Con(ZFC) are true and there are standard models of ZFC.  (Of course, I'm not saying that these things are provable in ZFC, only that they are true.)

Comment:  Joel David Hamkins.Yes of course.

Comment: Noah, thanks for the clarification.  I'm on FOM and I saw that posting, but I had forgotten the author's name.  I agree with you that in light of that context, this question is not appropriate for MO, and I have just voted to close as "off topic."

Comment:  Noah S. You rave. My question is put clearly and no any relation to my statements in other places has. Moreover I never addressed to whom or with intentions to check my proofs and the more so their sketches.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Many set theorists define that a model $\langle M,E\rangle$ of set
theory is *standard* to mean that the set membership relation $E$
of the model is the actual set membership relation $\in$,
restricted to objects in $M$.

The existence of such a standard model of ZFC is equivalent to the
existence of a well-founded model of ZFC, since every well-founded
model is isomorphic to its transitive collapse, via the Mostowski
collapse. The hypothesis that there is such a transitive model of
ZFC should be considered a very weak large cardinal axiom. For
example, the [transitive model of ZFC](http://cantorsattic.info/Transitive_ZFC_model) hypothesis appears near the bottom of the
large cardinal hierarchy in [Cantor's Attic](http://cantorsattic.info).

In particular, nearly all the usual large cardinal axioms imply
the existence of a standard model of ZFC, and so very few set
theorists want or expect ZFC to rule them out. Since we think that
large cardinals are consistent with ZFC, we also expect that it is
consistent with ZFC that there are standard models of ZFC.

For example, if $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal, then the set $H_\kappa$ of all sets having hereditary size less than $\kappa$ forms a transitive model of ZFC. Under the Grothendieck Universe Axiom, there will be a proper class of such inaccessible cardinals, and so the entire set-theoretic universe will be the union of such standard set models of ZFC.

Indeed, I would say much more: it is a fundamental part of the
reflection paradigm, the view that truths in the whole
set-theoretic universe are increasingly found in proper initial
segments of it, that we should expect many initial segments of the
universe to be ZFC models, and these will be standard models. This
is the kind of philosophical justification that one often hears
for various large cardinal hypotheses.

Meanwhile, it is easy to see that if ZFC is consistent, then it is consistent with ZFC that there is no standard model of ZFC. To prove this, take any model of ZFC. If it has no transitive models of ZFC, then we're done. If it does have a transitive model, then it will have an $\in$-minimal transitive model of ZFC, and this will be a model of ZFC having no transitive models of ZFC.

Furthermore, since every transitive model of ZFC has exactly the same arithmetic truths as the ambient universe, it follows that if there is a transitive model of ZFC, then there is one having no transitive model of ZFC, in which Con(ZFC) still holds.  In particular, ZFC+Con(ZFC), if consistent, cannot prove the existence of a standard model of ZFC. One may iterate this to the [consistency hierarchy](http://cantorsattic.info/Transitive_ZFC_model#Consistency_hierarchy) of models of ZFC. Basically, no amount of iterating the Con operator will get you to the existence of a standard model of ZFC, and this seems relevant for your revised question.

Finally, let me point out that if ZFC is inconsistent, then of course it is strong
enough to prove any assertion, including the one you ask about,
and so we cannot say for sure that ZFC doesn't prove your 
assertion without going beyond ZFC in our axioms.

Comment: Hi Joel. Do the statements ‘The consistency of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ does not imply the existence of a standard model of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $’ and ‘The existence of a standard model of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is strictly stronger than the consistency of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $’ mean $$ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \rightarrow \mathsf{SM}, $$ or do they mean $$ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \rightarrow \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{SM})? $$

Comment: These statements are what I see in most standard texts on set theory, and they somehow seem to mean $$ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \rightarrow \mathsf{SM}, $$ which I am unable to prove. I had a discussion with Asaf over at Math StackExchange about the proof of $$ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \rightarrow \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{SM}), $$ which we can rewrite as $$ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{SM}). $$

Comment: *Proof* Suppose instead that $$ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \vdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{SM}). $$ Then as $$ \mathsf{ZFC} \vdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{SM}) \rightarrow \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})), $$ we would obtain $$ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \vdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})), $$ which contradicts Gödel’s Second Incompleteness Theorem **if $ \mathsf{ZF} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is consistent**. $ \blacksquare $

Comment: The problem is: How can I remove the ‘if $ \mathsf{ZF} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is consistent’ clause so that I get a proof of $$ \mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{SM})? $$ Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Leonard, you can't remove that assumption, since if $\text{ZF}+\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ is inconsistent, then $\text{ZF}\vdash\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})\to\text{anything}$. All nonprovability results take place under a consistency assumption, and you shouldn't think that we haven't proved the final non-provability result, since we have proved it under the relevant consistency assumption. Note that any assertion of the form $\text{ZFC}+\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})\not\vdash\psi$ outright implies that $\text{ZFC}+\text{Con}(\text{ZFC})$ is consistent.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Joel. One more thing. Which of the two interpretations is correct: $ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \rightarrow \mathsf{SM} $ or $ \mathsf{ZFC} \nvdash \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \rightarrow \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{SM}) $?

Comment: Both are true, assuming the consistency of ZFC+Con(ZFC), since SM implies Con(ZFC) and also Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC)).

Comment: Am I right to guess that $ \mathsf{SM} $ implies $ \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})) $ comes from the fact that $ \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) $ is an absolute $ \mathcal{L}_{\text{Set}} $-formula? This should be the final gap in my understanding. Thanks once again!

Comment: Yes, that is right. The standard model has the same proofs that $V$ does, and so since $V$ thinks Con(ZFC), it follows that M does also, and so we get Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC)).

Comment: @Joel The Cantor attic website is malfunctioning, and it exposes some of your data. Also: how do you get to "and this will be a model of ZFC having no transitive models of ZFC."? Did you mean to say that "If it does have a transitive model, then _that_ model will have an $\in$-minimal transitive model of ZFC, and this will be a model of ZFC having no transitive models of ZFC."? Because the model you talk about is not transitive, so need not contain any supposed $\in$-smaller transitive model inside its $\in$-minimal transitive model. Just to check if I understand it correctly (I'm a noob).

Comment: Yes, I think you've got it. But an $\in$-minimal element of a transitive set is also $\in$-minimal in the ambient universe, so the quibble is not necessary.

Comment: @Jori: this might a little bit off-topic, but if these things about models-in-models are interesting to you, try to prove the following puzzling fact: every model of $ZFC$ contains a model of $ZFC$ as an element (that is, for every $M \models ZFC$ there is a set $N \in M$  such that $M$ believes $N$ is a first-order structure and $N \models ZFC$ (but $M$ might not know about the latter) ;)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins But the arbitrary model you select when you say "take any model of ZFC", which you get from Con(ZFC), is not necessarily transitive. In your sentence _"If it does have a transitive model, then **it** will have an ∈-minimal transitive model of ZFC"_, the "it" I bold-faced, what model does it refer to? The transitive model, or the original model? Maybe that clarifies it for me.

Answer (score 12):

Joel has explained that the existence of standard models and a negative answer to the question follow from large cardinal axioms.  He also mentioned, in the context of philosophical justification for large cardinal axioms, "the reflection paradigm, the view that truths in the whole set-theoretic universe are increasingly found in proper initial segments of it".  Let me add that the existence of standard models follows from (ZFC plus) mere acceptance (in an appropriate sense) of the very notion of "truths in the whole set-theoretic universe".  More precisely, suppose we add to the language of ZFC an additional predicate symbol Sat, intended to denote satisfaction, in the whole universe, of formulas of the original language of ZFC.  Suppose we add to the ZFC axioms the clauses that specify Sat by induction on formulas.  And suppose we also extend the axiom scheme of replacement by allowing formulas of the enlarged language.  Then, by formalizing a downward Löwenheim-Skolem argument, we can prove that ZFC has standard models, in fact ones of the form $V_\kappa$.  (We actually get more, namely $V_\kappa$'s that are elementary submodels of the universe, with respect to the original language of ZFC.)  In other words, for the limited sort of "truths in the whole set-theoretic universe" needed in proving the existence of standard models of ZFC, the reflection principle mentioned by Joel becomes provable, once one incorporates the relevant notion of truth into the theory.

Comment: Very good. And it may be worthwhile pointing out that your theory is a proper part of Kelly-Morse set theory, which proves the existence of such satisfaction predicates not only with respect to first-order truth, but also with respect to satisfaction for assertions involving any given class predicate parameter. So one also gets Sat relative to Sat, and so on transfinitely.